# How to modify url before following it in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new with scrapy and this is my second spider:

```
class SitenameScrapy(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "sitename"
    allowed_domains = ['www.sitename.com', 'sitename.com']
    rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), follow=True)]

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['http://www.sitename.com/']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_cat)

    def parse_cat(self, response):
        links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            if ('/category/' in link.url):
                yield response.follow(link, self.parse_cat)
            if ('/product/' in link.url):
                yield response.follow(link, self.parse_prod)

    def parse_prod(self, response):
        pass
```

My problem is that sometimes I have links like `http://sitename.com/path1/path2/?param1=value1&param2=value2` and for me, param1 is not important and I want to remove it from url before `response.follow`. I think I can do it with `regex` but I'm not sure that it is 'right way' for scrapy? Maybe I should use some kind of rule for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use the [url_query_cleaner](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.url_query_cleaner) method from [w3lib](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)'s library. Something like:

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
...
....
    def parse_cat(self, response):
        links = LinkExtractor().extract_links(response)
        for link in links:
            url = url_query_cleaner(link.url, ('param2',))
            if '/category/' in url:
                yield response.follow(url, self.parse_cat)
            if '/product/' in url:
                yield response.follow(url, self.parse_prod)
```

Comment: Just to add the other way around, specify which parameters to remove from the query string leaving all others: `url = url_query_cleaner(link.url, ('param1',), remove=True)`.